# Customize toolbar's menu items

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar

[image]

I have this in my toolbar, the text comes from toolbar's xml layout, while the magnifier icon comes from menu.xml for the page,
I have set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to this 'change city' RelativeLayout but still there is too much space between magnifier and Change city, 
How will I be able to remove this gap?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/location_change_RL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_icon">
```

menu.xml

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.discover.fitternity.activities.HomeScreenActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/fitternity_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is advisable or not but it does the trick for me several time. Try for yourself once.

Add this to your relative layout.

```
android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
```

Change 20 to whatever dimension fits for you.

Comment: I did it, but problem with this one is that, not my text is getting cut, menu item's whitespace  is overlapping 'change city', but not going away..